# TypeChecking with a reference to GrailsApplication property

Tags: grails, groovy, typechecking

I have a service which I want to use the TypeChecked annotation for.

It has some references to properties in the Config.groovy that are pulled in by doing:

```
...grailsApplication.config.myprop1.mysubprop1
```

In my Config groovy, it looks like this:

```
myprop1.mysubprop1 = true
```

But, when I used the TypeChecked annotation the lines as above give me compile errors:

```
 [Static type checking] - No such property: enabled for class: java.lang.Object
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can u show the actual service method where TypeChecked is used?

Comment: I think ConfigSlurper access is too dynamic to be type checked. Maybe farm the config access off to a method that isn't checked (or is marked CompileDynamic if you've just marked the whole class static)